# Reference a value (string) of a formula and check whether cells (sentences) contains the value

Tags: excel, formula, countif

I am currently trying to create an Excel formula to check whether cells containing some sentences contains a specific word.

Tricky part is that I want to read the value of another formula for the word to be checked. Example below:

```
      A        B
1   Apple     Amanda wants to buy some apple...
2   Orange    The price of orange in current market...
```

Where the content of A1 came from a formula. I am trying to create a formula to check whether B1 contains A1.

And I currently have

```
Formula 1 =  CELL("contents",A1) // To get cell content
Formula 2 =  COUNTIF(B1:B2,"*Apple*") // To find whether "Apple" appears
```

But I cant combine these two formulas to create...

```
COUNTIF(B1:B2,"*CELL("contents",A1)*") // Results I am trying to get
```

Can any Excel wiz help me with this please? Ideally I am looking for a method without having to result to Macro.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this works for you:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B2,"* " & CELL("contents",A1) & " *")
```

Since you want Apple as a wildcard (`"*Apple*"`), you can wrap the result from first formula as a wildcard by `"*" & formula & "*"` and entering it in the second.

Comment: I'm very glad it helped you. You were very close :). You can always combine cells/formulas with `&`. Take care :)!

Comment: @Wizhi - Thinking about it, you may want to add a space around the word you want to look for.  Depending on the word, this formula would return positive for "bar" in "the baritone singer...", or "car" in "cartoons are funny..." for example. But doing `....(B1:B2,"* "&...&" *")` would only find the full word.

Comment: @BruceWayne, Thank you for pointing out that!! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not `=SEARCH(A1,B1)`?  If an error is returned, the value is not found.

`=IFERROR(SEARCH(A1,B1),"Not found")`

Or `COUNTIF()` with wildcards:

```
=COUNTIF(B1,"*"&A1&"*")
```